# Redirect to specific url on button click in php file instead of to default woocommerce shop

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to change on a default php button function that redirects users to webshop so that it can redirect users to a custom url instead. This is the code responsible for this

```
<?php $proceed_booking_text = efora_get_field('proceed_booking_text');
                if(!empty($proceed_booking_text)){ ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php if($product->is_in_stock()){ ?>
                            <button type="submit" class="tg-btn tg-btn-lg btn-cart-ajax"><span><?php echo esc_attr(efora_get_field('proceed_booking_text')); ?></span></button>
                        <?php } else{ ?>
                            <button type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="tg-btn tg-btn-lg"><span><?php esc_attr_e('Not Available','efora'); ?></span></button>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

I have tried the the GOTO statement but only got a php error so I'm thinking I didn't use the statement properly.

Comment: GOTO has nothing whatsoever to do with this. These buttons seem to submit a form, so you would need to specify a different form action, if(!) if want to send the form data to that other URL - that can be done using the [`formaction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction) attribute on the button. If you don’t want to actually send the form data to the other URL however, either replace the button with a link, or add a click handler via JavaScript that prevents the default action, and goes to the other URL instead (via assignment to `location.href`)

Comment: Fantastic! It's the formaction attribute I needed. Thank you!!